# Oracle SQL String starts with ‘987’ or ‘I’

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL Developer. I need to find the rows where column1 starts with ‘987’ or ‘I’. Column1 is a String(18). Some sample patterns in this column include: 9(9), 9(12), and others. I am not familiar with the code to see how a column starts with certain values in Oracle SQL. Sample Code is below. Attempt below.

Code

```
select * from table1
where column1
```

Attempt Code

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1,
                '987') "REGEXP_SUBSTR"
  FROM table1;
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [SQL "like" operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `LIKE`.

```
select * 
from table1
where column1 like '987%' or column1 like 'I%';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
where regexp_like(column1, '^(987|I)')
```

Comment: This one should be marked as a more convenient answer.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE hs(WH VARCHAR2(100));

SELECT
  *
FROM
  hs
WHERE
  REGEXP_LIKE(WH,'^987|^I', 'i')
ORDER BY WH;